# cannot convert type struct to struct in c# unmanaged

Tags: c#, visual-c++

I have vc++ MFC application code having two structure like below

structA a1;
structB b1;

```
a1 = (structA*)&b1;
```

i want to convert this code in c# application i tried like this

```
a1 = (structA)b1;
```

> received error --> cannot convert type 'Test.structB' to
>   'Test.structA'

kindly suggest how to solve this issue

Comment: I do not think you can do this in C# using a `struct` data type... but you can with a `Class.`  You may want to look up Class’s and Inheritance. I am just guessing this may be what you are looking for.

Comment: In c# also i used struct datatype in test class. class test{structA a1;structB b1}

Comment: we can directly convert from one struct to another in vc++ but in c# how can i do that

Comment: I am pretty sure in C# you cannot cast/covert one `structA` variable to another `structB` variable directly. You could easily convert the `struct` properties to a class and do what you are trying to do. I am guessing (since you do not show what properties `sructA` and `structB` contain) there are similar properties in each `struct`. So `ClassA` would contain those similar properties, then `ClassB` would be an inherited/derived class from `ClassA`. Then you could do something like ClassB b= new ClassB(); then ClassA a=b; Since `ClassB` is derived from `ClassA` this will be a legal assignment.

Comment: Do you need to interface with unmanaged code that requires you to keep structs like this?